# `Real` tag adjustment

Tags: discussion, tags

**Revised** 
    $^\color{red}\wedge$  
**Proposal**
to consolidate [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) and [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries)
under the more-aptly named [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries)
and to redescribe [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) in order to avert my suggesting a new tag.

These two tags now mostly overlap,
and [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) doesn't naturally imply *well-known*.

   $^\color{red}\wedge$

Current [description](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/real/info)
of [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real)
$~\rlap{\,\raise-12mu{_\color{red}\wedge}}$
(would be moved to [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries), which has no description yet):

> **A tag used to specify a real-world puzzle,
>       that is well known, and usually unsolved.**
>   
>   This tag is most generally used when posting a real-world puzzle/mystery.
>   It is almost always an unsolved mystery,
>   and there is usually a very low expectation of the community
>   actually finding an answer.

The main line could be changed to something like:
**A real-world puzzle that is well known for being or having been unsolved.**

 $^\color{red}\wedge$

Now uniquely under [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real):

> $\kern19em$ (keep in [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) as it is not well known) 
>   [Computations of
>    an old woman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29941)
>         (unsolved)   $^\color{red}\wedge$
>   
>   [A good puzzle is a
>    double-edged sword](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18782)
>     (solved?!)

Now uniquely under [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries) (see also
[Posting famous
 unsolved puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3295)):

> [The 2 million, er, 20 dollar problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17106)

Now under both:

> [The Beale Papers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25128)
>   
>   [Unsolved Mysteries:
>    Kryptos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25931)
>   
>   [Unsolved Mysteries:
>    D'Agapeyeff cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29372)
>   
>   [Unsolved Mysteries:
>    Magic Square of Squares](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23944)

**Proposed** (re)description of [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real)
or of yet another new tag, perhaps [practical](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practical):

> **A real-world puzzle from practical experience.**
>   
>   This tag is for puzzles that have actually been encountered and solved
>   $\llap{\color{red}{ \raise8mu\underline{\phantom{\small and~solved}}} \, }$
>   in the course of coincidental activity.
>   
>    
>   [Computations of
>    an old woman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29941)
>   
>    $^\color{red}\wedge$
>   
>   [Euclid's orchard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25009)
>   
>   [Halve time
>    with two timers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25606)
>   
>   [Odd hours with
>    two timers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25610)
>   
>   [Day and night
>    of the two timers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25812)
>   
>   (others under the radar)

Interesting puzzles that arise in the wild have consequential solutions.
A broad understanding of puzzles includes this aspect.
An enhanced sensitivity toward this could bring us
unusual examples beyond imagination alone.

Comment: The description of real-world practical puzzles can be improved, of course. Already not so enthusiastic about the term *coincidental*

Comment: I think the description for [tag:real] should be used for [tag:unsolved-mysteries] instead, but the "computations of an old woman" question should not be retagged because it is not a well-known mystery.

Comment: Revised slightly, hopefully in a way that reflects @f'' 's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) tag was revised a month and a half ago as shown
and [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries)
was given a description around the same time.
Hurray!

I'll check for comments here
before adding [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) to the puzzles suggested in the question,
along with one or two others that have surfaced,
in a day or two.

[real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real)
[Summary:](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/20731/revisions)

> A tag used to specify a real **-world** puzzle,
>   <del>that is well known, and usually unsolved</del>
>   **which usually do not have a solution at the time of posting.
>     This can include widely-known puzzles
>     that have remained unsolved for some time**.

[real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real)
[Description:](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/20730/revisions)

> This tag is most generally used when posting a real-world puzzle/mystery,
>   **and as such, the ability of the poster to provide additional details
>     may be limited.**
>   It <del>is almost always an</del>
>      **can represent a widely-known**
>   unsolved mystery, <del>and</del>
>                     **for which**
>   there is <del>usually a very</del>
>            **often a**
>   low expectation of the community actually finding an answer.